# Modern pass-through authentication

Tags: database, openid-connect, saml

In a Microsoft environment one can set up a web application that will pass the credentials directly to SQL Server so that permissions are set closest to the data. How can this be achieved in modern applications using SAML and OpenID?

Comment: Not sure I understand? You mean credentials to access the SQL server? That has nothing to do with how the user authenticates with an IDP.

Comment: @nzpcmad thanks for responding! So at the moment the database (for example SQL Server) only has Service accounts (for example AppPool users in IIS), and the website (for example ASP.NET) checks whether user can access a table against another arbitrary table we created called App_Perm (table_id,username,has_access). I want to eliminate App_Perm and manage permissions in the database. It is possible in the old approach of Windows Authentication (kerb ticket), but not sure how it's done in using an IdP (SAML, Oauth etc.)

Answer (score 0):

You need to split out authentication and authorisation.

Authentication is done by the IDP. You have to have valid credentials in the IDP repository.

Authorisation can be done by the IDP using e.g. groups in the repository. The IDP has rules that say e.g. only members of group x in the repository can access application y.

For e.g. ADFS, the repository is AD.

It can also be done by the application using a DB. Same principle - only members of group x in the DB can access application y.

Or the IDP can pass a token containing claims derived from attributes in the repository. The application can use these claims to make decisions or the client middleware can do this e.g. OWIN with a decoration like:

[Authorize(Roles="Admin")]

All these cases are valid.

Comment: Thanks @nzpcmad ! I think I get it on the groups side. The one thing i'm still trying to get my head around is how will the database (SQL Server) would know the user that the query is coming from (who authenticated against ADFS using SAML)?

Comment: Configure ADFS to pass the user's UPN as NameID and pass this as a claim.